# Phonegap Splash Screen Disappear after few seconds in iPhone 6(iOS 8.3) issue

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, xcode6, phonegap-build

When i click on application icon in iPhone6 , splash screen is opened but it remains only for 2 seconds and then disappear leads to crashing of app.

I have also added splash screens for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 + of resolution
1242*2208 px (Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png) and 750 *1334(Default-667h@2x.png) in splash folder.

I am using xcode 6.3.2 with iOS SDK 8.3.

It is working on iPad and iPod(iOS 8.3).

Answer (score 1):

The application crash has to come from your code because i just tested a clean project setup with the splashscreen plugin and there is no issue.

Before you start working on a project you should read the very informative readme which is available for every single cordova plugin.

So you want to set the splashscreen duration to another value, no problem. Like it is described in the [Cordova Splashscreen-Plugin Documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen).

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
```

and

```
setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 2000);
```

will do the trick. I would recommend you to call the splashscreen directly after the `deviceReady`-Event. Then you should start with your first function and include the `...show()` inside it. The `...hide()` goes into your last function and thats all.

Here you're able to find the preferences for your `config.xml` - [iOS Quirks](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#ios-quirks)

Before you use the commands above watch out for the [deviceReady-Event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) which is obligatory for the Splashscreen commands to work!

Comment: Thanks but I am using cordova 2.7.0.I have not used hide and show splashscreen methods. I have set AutoHideSplashScreen to true in config.xml.

Comment: Thanks..It works...But I have created project using cordova version 3.8.0 & Resources folder does not contain de.lproj, en.lproj ...So how do i set localization?

Answer (score 0):

The issue regarding splashscreen is resloved.
I have updated the cordova version to 3.8.0 and created new project with all settings.Finally it works on all devices.
        But there is one problem Resources folder does not contain en.lproj,de.lproj and Localizable.strings files .So How do i set localizations for this app??